# GestureRecognizer Interferes w/ MapKit Popup

Tags: ios, mapkit, uigesturerecognizer

I have a simple MapKit app working fine in iOS. It has annotation and when the user clicks on them, the little gray default popup is displayed with the title / subtitle. I even added a UIButton view into it.

So the problem is, I have a search bar above my map. I wanted to resignFirstResponder from the search box whenever the user clicks on the MapView, so I added a simple tap gesture responder. Worked great except now the little gray detail popups no longer show up (only the annotation pins)! I can still tap, zoom, move around etc. Just no popups.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
tap.delaysTouchesBegan = NO;
tap.delaysTouchesEnded = NO;
[mapView addGestureRecognizer:tap];


-(IBAction)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)geture {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Is it possible to have the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a delegate method similar to the following to arbitrate between touches that should go to my custom view's pan gesture recognizer and touches that should go to the scroll view that contained my custom view.  Something like it might work for you.

```
// the following UIGestureRecognizerDelegate method returns YES by default.
// we modify it so that the tap gesture recognizer only returns YES if
// the search bar is first responder; otherwise it returns NO.
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
  if ((gestureRecognizer == self.tapGestureRecognizer) &&
      (gestureRecognizer.view == self.mapView) &&
      [searchBar isFirstResponder])
  {
    return YES;  // return YES so that the tapGestureRecognizer can deal with the tap and resign first responder
  }
  else
  {
    return NO;  // return NO so that the touch is sent up the responder chain for the map view to deal with it
  }
}
```